# Visual Studio 2010 Call to _locking() failing (errno = 22) when file pointer is above (2^32)-1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

We have a legacy application whose target platform is x86. The application reads and writes to a file, it also locks regions of the file. The app was limited to write only 2gb worth of file. But since we needed to app to support 2gb+, we had to change most of the calls. Basically _lseek and _tell where changed to _lseeki64() and _tell64(). Seeking a position past (2^32)-1 doesnt have any problems, as well as read() to that position. However when calling _locking(), I get a return val of -1 and an errno of 22.

This tells me that the offset and length I'm trying to _locking() can't be processed by the _locking() call. I tried targeting x64 but it looks like the tool set v100 is still not targeting the io.h for 64bit version of the library that i need.

I know this is a vague question, but is there a way around this, My last option is to port the code to use WIN32 API?

Comment: These legacy posix functions are in maintenance mode.  You'll have to write your own locking64() function.  Use the CRT source file locking.c available in vc/crt/src for inspiration.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you very much! Why this skipped my mind I don't know... I ended up looking at v2012 toolset source and made one my self for locking as its not an option for us to target a higher toolset. This is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CRT libraries you would need to port your code to equivalent WIN32 API Functions. Then you can use [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx) function which supports locking upto (2^64) - 1.

Mostly all of the CRT functions have a direct equivalent WIN32 functions, so porting code will not be difficult. But I would recommend to do thorough testing to uncover idiosyncrasies between CRT & WIN32.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that moving the code to use WIN32 API would be my last option.